# Esconder o ícone do APP

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou precisando criar um APP do tipo serviço, sem ícone ou qualquer vestígio de que está sendo executado.

Já consegui ocultar tudo que preciso e tudo funciona bem.

Porém, eu estou usando BroadcastReceiver para carregar o app automaticamente no boot do OS. E quando isso ocorre, o APP pára, pois não encontra uma Activity para carregar.

Isso só ocorre quando eu escondi o ícone. Sem esconder o ícone, tudo normal.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Estou escondendo com:

```
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

E os trechos do BroadCast:

Manifesto:

```
    <receiver android:name="simpress.mobileinfo.MainActivity$MyBroadCastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Classe broadcast receiver:
    public static class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cria um  `.png` transparent.

Comment: Se a aplicação não é para ter uma *Activity* (não necessita de interagir com o usuário) então o *BroadcastReceiver* deve lançar um serviço e não uma *Activity*.

Comment: Bacana, isso eu não tinha me ligado mesmo. Então, minha Main não extenderá Activity, mas deverá extender uma classe de serviço. Qual seria essa classe?

Comment: Veja o guia na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Olá amigo vc consegui fazer o BroadcastReceiver funcionar sem uma Activity?